# PHP - Can you use prepared statements with a * and ORDER BY?

Tags: php, mysqli

Can you use prepared statements with a * and ORDER BY?

Because I can't figure out how to do it. I've been trying for awhile now. I've looked at a few other threads but haven't found out how. If not, how could I go about getting a mysqli query like this and prevent sql-injection?

Would appreciate any ideas or critiques.

Thanks,
Matt

```
<?php
    require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db-connect.php');
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY ? DESC LIMIT 1")){
    $id = 'id';

    $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    echo $row['title'];


    $stmt->free_result();

    $stmt->close();

    }

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: none - it comes up blank

Comment: The first thing this tells you is that you need to enable error reporting and / or verify the variables you're operating over to make sure your connector didn't report an error back to you.

Comment: well I was trying to set it to my id column with a placeholder which apparently doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can't use placeholders for column names. You will need to either hard code it in:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
```

or do something like this to allow user input:

```
switch ($_POST['sortby']) {
    // Add all possible column names here
    case 'id':
    case 'col2':
    case 'col3':
    case 'col4':
    case 'col5':
        $sortby = $_POST['sortby'];
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Invalid sort by");
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY `$sortby` DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: or another alternative is a whitelist array of columns, the just use `in_array`

Comment: @Ghost Yes, that would work as well, and less lines of code.